# Take the Sigma of a factorial with unknown variable (using sympy?)

Tags: python, sum, sympy, factorial

Good day,

I am trying to write a function for the following equation:

[image: Eurlang B]

Where B and N are given and I am solving for A.

I was reading up and it seemed like sympy was the way to go so I started to declare the known variables, but when it came to the sigma notation with the factorial, I had no idea of how to approach it since A is an unknown.

Here is what I came up with:

```
from sympy import Eq, var, solve
from math import *

A = var('A')
channels = raw_input("Enter the number of channels: ")
#GOS = raw_input("Enter GOS: ")

Sigma = A
for i in range(0,channels+1):
  Sigma += (A**i / factorial(i))

# equation = Eq((A**channels / factorial(channels)) / Sigma) 
# print solve(equation)
```

which gives me the error `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects`

This makes sense to me, but my lack of knowledge with sympy makes me unable to figure out how to fix it.

EDIT: Looking around a bit more, I edited my code to this:

```
  from sympy import *

  A = symbols('A')
  channels = raw_input("Enter the number of channels: ")
  GOS = raw_input("Enter GOS: ")

  Sigma = summation(A**i / factorial(i), (i, 0,channels))
  print Sigma



  # equation = Eq((A**channels / factorial(channels)) / Sigma)
```

Now I get `NameError: name 'i' is not defined`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the error ( name 'i' not defined) is because you havent defined it. so you need to give an initial value for i.

secondly, I have tried to make your program run. got an error free solution with this code:

```py
from sympy import *

A = symbols('A')
channels = raw_input("Enter the number of channels: ")
GOS = raw_input("Enter GOS: ")

# note that I convert the string 'channel' to an int
# convert to float if channel could also be a floating number
channels = int(channels) 
Sigma = A
for i in range(0,channels+1):
    Sigma += (A**i / factorial(i))
print Sigma
```

The result,

inputs: channels = 3, GOS = 1

output: `A**3/6 + A**2/2 + 2*A + 1`

EDIT: Out of interest I started looking further into your problem (also because I could realize this question would not stop just by a datatype issue).
The Solve function has 2 inputs, the equation and the symbol to calculate.
it solves the equation == 0. so the variable B has to be subtracted from the equation. (I supposed the input GOS is the B variable in the function)

```
equation = (A**channels / factorial(channels)) / Sigma
print(solve(equation-int(GOS), A))
```

running the code with the lines above (add them under the code) gave these outputs:

```
A**3/6 + A**2/2 + 2*A + 1
[-2 - sqrt(2), -2 + sqrt(2)]
```

I must notice that if the GOS does not intersect the function it gives large results with additional parameter I (capital i, might indicate imaginary i).
I hoped this helped solving your problem.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. And thank you for your assumption in the edit. I do remember reading that solve sets it equal to 0, so I probably would have been banging my head against the wall not knowing why the answer is not correct. I've filtered out all of the complex and negative solutions and it seems to be working perfectly. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

To describe a similar sum as at the top of the page, when I use the asmeurer's recommendation `summation`, I get the error -TypeError: 'Symbol' object is not subscriptable." What could be the possible cause of this error? I imported the libraries below. There is a continuation of the code, but I did not add it to avoid confusion.

```
import sympy as sympy 
from sympy import *       
from sympy import summation, symbols

class FQ(): 
def integrate(self):
   for k in range(1, self.Nt):
      i = symbols('i', integer=True)
      self.Sigma = summation(self.u[i+1][j], (i, 0, k - 1))
```

---

#second attempt

```
def integrate(self, alpha, Nt, Nx, L):
    
    for k in range(1, self.Nt):   
      for j in range(1, self.Nx-1):  
        #define sum
        for i in range(1, self.Nt):
          Sigma = summation(u[i+1][j], (i, 0, k-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also perform the summation in SymPy using the `summation` function

```
i = symbols('i')
summation(A**i/factorial(i), (i, 0, N)
```

Another note: you are starting with `Sigma = A`, meaning your final result is `A + ΣA^i/i!` instead of just `ΣA^i/i!` (you can see in the output from @Petrus1904's answer there is a `2*A` instead of `A`). If you want to use a loop to compute a summation you should initialize the variable to 0.